# ERROR: 180: EXCEPTION thrown ('dev!'): - and ERROR:> aqsrv> 70: Exception caught in (null) - Error -1

Tags: javascript, android, ios, audio, titanium

every time I call my function to use .wav files I get these errors:

```
ERROR: 180: EXCEPTION thrown ('dev!'): -
```

and

```
ERROR:> aqsrv> 70: Exception caught in (null) - Error -1
```

it always happens in the line of `play()`.

It only happens in IOS -  on android it runs well.

Function:

```
function sonido() {
    var cont=0;
    //console.log(arregloDetalles[cont].tVelocidad);
    var intervalo=setInterval(function() {
        if(bnaddetener==1){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
        }           
        if(arregloDetalles[cont].click_clack==1) {
            soundclick.play();

        } else {
            soundclack.play();
            console.log("Clack");
        }
        cont++;
        if(cont==arregloDetalles.length) {
            banderaclick=1;
            cont=0;
        }
    } ,arregloDetalles[cont].tVelocidad);
}
```

declaration of .wav files:

```
var soundclick = Titanium.Media.createSound({
        url:'/sonidos/beep-8.wav',
        preload:true
});
soundclick.addEventListener('complete', function(e) { soundclick.release(); });

var soundclack = Titanium.Media.createSound({
        url:'/sonidos/beep-7.wav',
        preload:true
});
soundclack.addEventListener('complete', function(e) { soundclack.release(); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like is trying to get the input device sample rate. That will not work on iOS Simulator, you need to test on a real device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html