# xcode 6 App Crash Error Message What does it mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

In xcode 6, my app crashes on launch and gives me this error in the console. What does this error mean?

```
2015-03-22 11:36:18.908 BallProject0032[726:7603] 11:36:18.908 ERROR:      180: EXCEPTION thrown ('!dev'): -libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CAException
```

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995254/error-180-exception-thrown-dev-and-error-aqsrv-70-exception-caught) when you searched?

Comment: @trojanfoe I was unable to make sense out of the thins that I found while searching.